# authentication with google and facebook with protected route in MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, routes, protected

can anyone tell me
protected route in authentication with facebook or google

protected route like.
login user can't access signup page until logout. and login user can't go to again login page until logout.
i want to know protected route in authentication with google and facebook.

and i also want to know authentication with google and facebook

using nodejs react js mongodb  // MERN

Comment: [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979202/2873538)